# Make an invite to every server bot is in

Tags: bots, discord, discord.js

So I want to make an invite to every server bot is inside.
The bot needs `"CREATE_INSTANT_INVITE"` permission within the channel.

I made something like this but it seems not to work.

```js
    client.guilds.cache.forEach(guild => {
        guild.channels.cache.first().createInvite()
          .then(inv => console.log(`${guild.name} | ${inv.url}`));
      });
```

Error:

```
DiscordAPIError: Unknown Channel
```

I think I get the error because bot tries to make an invite but he does not have permission to do so.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Good afternoon,

The `first()` channel is probably a category. You're not able to make invites on categories :sob: however, you could filter the guild's channels so that categories are not included.
Then you need to get a `random()` channel and log that.

```js
    client.guilds.cache.forEach(guild => {
        guild.channels.cache.filter(x => x.type != "category").random().createInvite()
          .then(inv => console.log(`${guild.name} | ${inv.url}`));
      });
```

The rest of your code was fine and should work as expected.

I hope this helps, don't forget to upvote the answer and mark it with a tick if it works.

Comment: Yea it's probably a category, another issue is that the bot may not have permission to create an invite for that channel

Comment: You could also use `.map()` to map a list of invites, instead of going through each guild individually

Comment: Thanks for helping mate.

Comment: No problem :D Anytime.

Comment: I got an error `TypeError: guild.channels.cache.filter(...).random(...).createInvite is not a function`